# How to transform purchase DataFrame to a Spark DistributedMatrix type in order to calculate similarities between items?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cosine-similarity

I want to convert a `Spark DataFrame` to a `CoordinateMatrix` and then `RowMatrix` so that I calculate cosine similarities between columns afterwards.

The Dataframe is the purchases of users:
Data Sample:

```
 arr = np.array([
['b5ad805c-f295-4852-82fc-961a88',12732936],
['0FD6955D-484C-4FC8-8C3F-DA7D28','Gklb38'],
['0E3D17EA-BEEF-4931-8104',12909841],
['CC2877D0-A15C-4C0A-AD65-762A35C1','12645715'],
['CC2877D0-A15C-4C0A-AD65-762A35C1',12909837],
['6AC9C45D-A891-4BEA-92B1-04224E9C65ED', '12894376'],
['CFF7BAB7-C5E1-490D-B257-AE58CA071362', 'Gklb38' ]])

df_purchases = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['user_id','basket'])
```

where **user_id** is the user ID who bought the product ID (item) in the field **basket**

Originally, I used Pandas DataFrame and `crosstab`:

```
  df_cross = pd.crosstab(df_purchases.user_id, df_purchases.basket).astype('bool').astype('int')
```

to have purchases per user in row and product_id(s) as columns, where if the user purchased ID1, **1 = purchased, otherwise = 0**:

```
|----------|-------------|---------|----------|
|  user_id | item_id1    | item_id2| item_id3 |
 ---------------------------------------------
| user_1   |      0      |    1    |    0     |
----------------------------------------------- 
| user_2   |      1      |    0    |    0     |
----------------------------------------------- 
| user_3   |      0      |    1    |    1     |
-----------------------------------------------
```

After having the data in that format, I calculate similarities. But as I have a big dataset of more than 50000 items and  20000 users, I need to replace the original method using crosstab into using a Spark DistributedMatrix (**CoordinateMatrix** or **RowMatrix**) to leverage distributed computations.

```
    # Create a Spark DataFrame from Pandas
     spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df_cross)
```

I'm confused about how to do it as I'm new in using spark and even though I found some insights from this [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44803759/6837132), I couldn't figure out how to build the `CoordinateMatrix` and index the **fields** as they are of **type String**, while **CoordinateMatrix** works with **int Type**.

So my questions are:

- How to build the `CoordinateMatrix`?
- How to index the fields and also be able to map back to their real ID  later after similarities calculations? (like if product ID is `GK38LB` and suppose its mapped index is 1. In the matrix of similarities I will have it presented as `1`. How to map that value to the original value?). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163248/how-to-get-item-id-from-cosine-similarity-matrix) is similar to mine but in Scala.

Comment: [Why not upload pictures of data/code when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). I may have a solution for you, but I can't see your data.

Comment: @pault thanks for the link. I corrected the question with a sample of data/code instead of images.